# Recurrence relations in haskell

Tags: haskell, recurrence

I'm new to Haskell and still haven't figured out how to do anything realistic.
I've looked at examples of recurrence relations but the implementation is too advanced for me at the moment.

I'm trying to set up the recurrence relation:

```
f(t,i) = (2/3)*f(t+1,i+1) + (1/3)*f(t+1,i-1)
```

but I can't figure out to set my types for the input to f(a,b) or how to define it in general.

Comment: Could you describe the computation you're trying to implement? What's the recurrence, what is the base case, etc?

Comment: Other than a base-case, that code looks fine to me.

Comment: due to the first one `f (t+1,i+1)` it might be really hard to find a base case as it seem to me that both of the arguments/items will grow unbounded

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve was for a statistics class:
 
"Assume that we play a game where at each stage we can win one dollar with probability 4/6
and lose one dollar with probability 2/6. We start with four dollars. If we lose all our money we
have to stop playing. What is the probability to reach the level of six dollars before time t = 8?"

My base cases are: `f(8,_) = 0` and `f(_,6)=1`
The answer to the problem is `f(0,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell defines functions a little differently from other languages - you don't wrap parameters in brackets, instead they are used in a similar way to maths where it means "do this bit first". So your function would look a little like this in haskell, where you just need a space between your function name and your variables

```
f t i = (2/3) * f (t+1) (i+1) + (1/3) * f (t+1) (i-1)
```

Also, to prevent an infinite loop, it's important you create a condition for the recursion to end, for example if you just want to return t when i is zero you can do this (this is a guess, I'm not sure what you'd like your condition to be, you can have more than one)

```
f t 0 = t
f 10 _ = 10
f t i = (2/3) * f (t+1) (i+1) + (1/3) * f (t+1) (i-1)
```

It's also considered good practice to add the function type (normally I would do this as my very first step)

```
f :: Float -> Float -> Float
f t 0 = t
f 10 _ = 10
f t i = (2/3) * f (t+1) (i+1) + (1/3) * f (t+1) (i-1)
```

Comment: have you tried running this? let's say with `f 1 1`? (In GHCi it will not take long to overflow the stack)

Comment: Thanks, @Carsten not with those args - I didn't know what his conditions were, so made something simple up to illustrate the idea - I've updated the answer now to have another condition :)